# Connecting the video stream from a DJI Matrice 100 camera to a Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi3, dji-sdk

I want to connect the video stream from a DJI Matrice 100 drone camera to a raspberry pi 3.

What mechanism is used to transmit the video from the drone?

Can I change it?

Comment: what version of ROS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Matrice uses DJI Lightbridge technology to transmit its video.

DJI Lightbridge 2 has been designed from the ground up to meet the requirements of professional broadcasting, offering high frame rates and HD live streaming.

Check out [this link](https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/github-platform-docs/ROS/README.html) for information on how to manage and manipulate the system using the SDK.

The video stream is specific to the choice of supported camera.

Comment: Unlikely, what is it youre trying to achieve with the raspberry pi?

Comment: I want to add an encryption to the video stream. I saw that there is an option to encrypt it by AES but I don't understand if the encryption is on the UART to the RF Port or to the video using LightBridge.. it is a very complicated system and I'd appreciate some help ! :)